# FileReader not working consistently Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a JS function where filereader is reading a local file and parsing it to use elsewhere. The function performs fine in debugger but not live. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function readFileAndDisplayItinerary() {
   var file=document.getElementById("fileName").files[0]; //<input id>
   var reader = new FileReader();
   var map = new Map();
   reader.onload = function(event){
   var json = JSON.parse(event.target.result);
   for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
        var obj = json[i];
        map.set(obj.name, obj.latitude + " " + obj.longitude);
     }
  };
reader.readAsText(file);
createItineraryTable(map);
}
```

Comment: Well, I was a bit lazy to try it out. So maybe you can share a sample input file content or putting some `console.log("blahblah")`s around or just share the developer tools console results when the problem occurs? Btw, welcome :)

Comment: What the result in production?

Comment: What is not working in the live version? Did you check for errors using the browser F12 tools?

Comment: Your question is like asking why your car doesn't work today when it did yesterday.  Are you getting errors when its live?  What is it actually doing?

Comment: @vahdet No errors in console, just the map is empty. It theoretically should get fields from JSON and put in map to be passed to another function, but live, the map is empty

Comment: @Amy only a warning about filelastmodified being deprecated